# Should I email a corrected version of my essay to graduate admissions?

Tags: graduate-admissions, application

I realized the writing sample I'd submitted for my grad school application (US grad school) had a small mistake that messed up the formatting of the first page. I'd written the authors' contributions in the footnote of the first page, and because of a small formatting problem, half of it had gone to the footnote on the second page and that half includs important information on authors' contribution. (And since it's a writing sample with multiple authors, authors' contribution should be crucial for the admission committee I guess.)

I've already submitted my application and can't make any changes, but there is still couple of days left till the deadline. Should I send the corrected version to the admissions, explain there was a formatting problem, and ask them to replace the old one with the correct one, or would that do more harm than good?

Comment: To the person who down-voted: It's usually considered good manners to at least leave some kind of indication why.

Comment: To the actual question: Are you sure it's an error? I have seen some books do this. Not usually, true, and not very often. But if the footnote is referenced close to the bottom of the page it can mean that to keep the footnote all on one page would leave a big white space at the bottom of the page.  Usually that shows that the author has gone overboard on the content of the footnote, which should probably be integrated into the the text or moved to an end note.

Answer (score 3):

You can send it. It probably isn't necessary. It probably won't be considered. But it won't hurt. Just include a note of apology for the bad formatting.

But an error like that should have no effect on your application.